# SQL Min(Date) issue with still getting all dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to get only records that are the min date of the orderID

I have the following setup:

```
select
op.OrderID,
op.id,
MIN(op.Date) AS Date
From OrderPermits op
GROUP BY 
Op.OrderId
op.id,
MIN(op.Date) AS Date
```

Orders has 1 to many order permits.

The problem here is that I am still getting duplicate order Id's when I only want the 1 order ID that is the min(date) for order permits???

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
select op.Date, op.OrderID, op.opid
from (
    select OrderID, MIN(Date) AS MinDate 
    From OrderPermits  
    GROUP BY OrderId 
) opm
inner join OrderPermits op on opm.OrderID = op.OrderID 
    and opm.MinDate = op.Date
```

Comment: This will return duplicates in case of ties on `MIN(date)`.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Agreed, it is up to the OP to decide whether this is acceptable with his/her particular data set.

Answer (score 4):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY Date) AS rn
        FROM    orderpermits
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

This is guaranteed to return one record per `OrderID`, even in case of ties on `MIN(Date)`.

You may want to read this article:

- [**SQL Server: Selecting records holding group-wise maximum**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/30/sql-server-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/)

Comment: To complex for such a trivial problem.

Comment: @Yves: could you please describe a flaw in my approach?

Comment: Erm. Sorry. Was not my intention to ruin your day.

Comment: @Yves: no problem. It takes three to five downvotes to ruin my day, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
   op.OrderID, op.id, op.Date
FROM
   dbo.OrderPermits op
WHERE
   op.Date = (SELECT MIN(op.Date) FROM dbo.OrderPermits WHERE OrderId = op.OrderId)
```

Comment: The @op wants to get rid of the duplicates on `OrderID`, not `id`.

Comment: Why there is a `GROUP BY` here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that (except for the multiple returns) your query does what you want...

```
select
op.OrderID,
op.id,
MIN(op.Date) AS Date
From OrderPermits op
Where op.Date = (Select Min(Date) from OrderPermits) // <-- Add this
GROUP BY
op.OrderID,
op.id,
MIN(op.Date) as Date
```

Though, if you only want one record returned, you could also do:

```
Select op.OrderID,
  op.Id,
  op.Date
From OrderPermits op
Where op.Date = (Select MIN(Date) from OrderPermits)
```

These will both still return multiple results if multiple records share the `MIN(Date)`.  I do not know if that is possible with your data or not.

Answer (score -1):

Can't try it now but shouln't you remove teh MIN(op.Date) from the group by clause ?